# Item-based recommender system with R

Tags: r, matrix, similarity, recommendation-engine

Actually I'm trying to build a simple item-based recommender system and I decided to use R due to my lack of programming knowledge.

Still, some issues remain so I'll try to be as methodic as possible to explain them.

### Log file

I start with a log file imported as a data frame containing many columns among which : The ID of the customers, the ID of the items and the transaction date.

Here's an overview of the log file

```
'data.frame':   539673 obs. of  3 variables:
$ cid: int  1 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 ...
$ iid   : int  1002 1345 1346 2435 6421 4356 1002 4212 ...
$ timestamp : int  1330232453 1330233859 13302349437 1330254065 1330436051
```

I succeeded to turn this log file into a matrix with the customers in lines , the products in columns and the timestamp (much easier to manipulate) of the transaction date when a transaction occurs between these first two elements.

So I end up with a matrix of 100000 rows and 3000 columns, which is pretty huge.

### Similarity matrix

From that point, I can create my item-based recommender system.

First, I binarize my matrix *m* in order to be able to compute the similarity:

```
mbin <- (m > 0) + 0
```

To compute the similarity, I use the cosine measure by a function:

```
getCosine <- function(x,y) 
{
cosine <- sum(x*y) / (sqrt(sum(x*x)) * sqrt(sum(y*y)))
return(cosine)
}
```

After creating a matrix for receiving the different similarity measures,

I created two loops to measure this one:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(mbin)) {
for(j in 1:ncol(mbin)) {
mbin.sim[i,j] <- getCosine((mbin[i]),(mbin[j]))
}}
```

This similarity matrix takes too long to be computed, that is why I only focus on retrieving one particular similiarity. 
Note that I've taken a random number *n*, I would also like to enter an item's name

```
n = 5
for(i in n) {
for(j in 1:ncol(mbin)) {
mbin.sim[i,j] <- getCosine(mbin[i],mbin[j])
}}
```

How can I achieve that?

### Building and applying the recommender

From this part, I'm stuck because I can't see how I can make an easy recommender which will take one item and recommender k users to it.

### Testing

Moreover, to test the recommender, I should be able to go back in time and to see if , from a certain date, I can predict the good users.

To do that, I know that I have to create a function which can give me the date of the n*th* transaction. Mathematically, it means that for a particular column, I have to get the n*th* non zero elements for that column. So I tried this but it only gives me the first one :

```
firstel <- function(x,n){
m <- head(x[x!=0],1)
m[n]
}
```

How can I do that? and moreover, How can I use this variable to discriminate between past and future events, with another function?

Sorry for this long post but I really wanted to show that I'm really into it and that I really want to overcome that step in order to begin the real analysis afterwards.

NB : I'm really doing that without complex packages due to the huge amount of data.

Comment: Removing MATLAB tag as you make no reference to it in your question.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, a mishandling!  thanks

Comment: Have you considered using recommenderlab package? it helps you use existing recommender functions.

Comment: Yes, for sureI worked on that option but considering the huge amount of data, my RAM memory is not enough due to the numerous duplication of the matrix that recommenderlab is doing. 

Moreover, with the recommenderlab, I don't have any control about what is going on, especially if I want to play with parameters. 

Thus, I'm struggling for a solution without package